# Clustered index, order on single single, without order by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, relational-database

I have a transaction table (single primary key) with millions of records and everyday 100s of records are getting added.

This table is then further used in Reconciliation and Settlement which happens on newly inserted records only, without any order.

Although, I have created a clustered index on the ID column but not sure whether it should be ASC or DESC. As most of the processing happens on newly inserted records so I was thinking to order the index as DESC but not sure.

I have already checked on several blogs and questions on StackOverflow about this but all of them are discussing composite clustered index with order by clause. In my case there is single column clustered index and no requirement for order by.

Comment: It doesn't matter, SQL Server can traverse the index from either first or last page with equal efficiency.

Comment: Thanks @RogerWolf for sharing comment. Could you please share some link or more details on it.

Comment: I don't think you will pick up these "newly added" records by a query like `select top (1000) * from dbo.Transactions order by Id desc`. If you do, you can forget about parallel processing and any kind of efficiency in general. Instead, you will look at some field that shows which workflow stage the transaction is currently on. And you will want an index on that field, trust me. In this case, the order of your clustered index is irrelevant.

Comment: I think you are right. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

It depends... For some operations, like ORDER BY, it does not matter as index is bidirectional, so sorting is not needed.

But for other operations, like Ranking, Index Scan, etc., it matters. SQL Engine is designed to perform forward index scan with parallelism, but if query optimizer needs a reverse index scan, such operation is single-threaded. So it may affect the performance if you choose incorrect sort order.

It really depends on the data and queries in your database, so I'm suggesting to capture most frequent user queries (against that table) and check their execution plans and IO stats for two different sort orders.

Also it can cause index fragmentation if data are added not in the same order as index sort order.